# in nodeJs request, how can we get the html after an ajax loading?

Tags: node.js, request

doing

```
var page_url = "http://skiferie.danskbilferie.dk/sidste_chance_uge7_norge_sverige.html";

http.get(page_url, (http_res) => {
    var data = "";

    http_res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });

    http_res.on("end", function () {
        resolve({data});                
    });
});
```

get's the correct HTML from that page, but how can I wait for the table of deals to be filled?

as [that page](http://skiferie.danskbilferie.dk/sidste_chance_uge7_norge_sverige.html) only fills the data I need after it loads, calling an ajax method to fill the data in... is there a wait for me to wait for such action to be completed?

Comment: in the `http_res` function brackets, you should have a request and response parameter

Comment: @mast3rd3mon only if you use it, it's optional. By my question is about how to wait for the `page_url` to have the ajax content... the code works fine as is, but I simply do not get the async loaded code as I'm getting the source code "as is".

Comment: its because you need both parameters, then you can use `res.status(200).json({"data": dataObject});` which will send data when complete

Comment: If you want to fully render a web page you will need something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#usage)

Comment: @balexandre I think you really can't get that async loaded data as you would need to run JS code like web browsers and render web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait until ajax will be loaded, you need to add timeout for your request. 
Your goal is to somehow tell script to wait for some period of time and than get rendered html.
You can implement such behavior as @GabrielBleu said, with [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#usage) and here is nice tutorial with example: [tutorial](https://codeburst.io/a-guide-to-automating-scraping-the-web-with-javascript-chrome-puppeteer-node-js-b18efb9e9921)
Or with [webdriver](http://webdriver.io/) or you can try with this [resource](https://www.sitepoint.com/headless-chrome-node-js/)

Comment: ahh, pretty slick, they have a `page.waitFor('body div.fitem-row.ski', { visible: true })` ... really nice, thxs !